# how to catch regex <right></>

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to find a way to make a list of everything between
`<right>`and `</>` tags 
This is my regex:

```
<right>([^<\/>]*)<\/>?
```

I'm currently missing this case:

- when there is only 1  tag in front: `<right>hi`
- when interlocked `<right><right>hello</></>` (for the case of nesting, the content inside will be viewed as text, the next card is processed as usual)

it will look like this:

```
case1:
<div style="text-align: right">
  hi
</>

case2:
<div style="text-align: right">
   <div style="text-align: right">
     hello
   </>
</>
```

This is where i try regex: https://regex101.com/r/ybO9cV/1 
thanks for your help !

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly bad news. To get the matches that are missing the trailing </> use `/<right>([^<\/>]*)(<\/>)?/g`

The nesting requirement cannot be satisfied with regex - [can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

Comment: Can you help me fix this case? `<right><right>hello</></>` It seems that if nested, the last tag `</>` will be ignored https://regex101.com/r/29S8H0/1

Comment: You can’t use regex for nested